# Express route not working - nodejs

Tags: node.js, express

I have a simple scenario. I am following Max tutorial.

My `http://localhost:3000/message` always returns index page. That is only the first route is working. The new route is not working. I am simply trying to put `node.hbs` on `/message`

> /routes/app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
    res.render('index');
});
router.get('/messsage', function (req, res, next) {
    res.render('node', { message: 'hello' });
});
module.exports = router;
```

> app.js

```
var appRoutes = require('./routes/app');
app.use('/', appRoutes);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    return res.render('index');
});
```

Comment: You have a typo in your route path: 'messsage` when the URL you are requesting has 'message'. 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is working. The requested URL `http://localhost:3000/message` is not matching any of your declared paths so it is defaulting to your custom 404 page which is the same as your index page. Without changing your code and simply requesting `http://localhost:3000/messsage` will match the path of `/messsage` on your router. It's a typo.